# Inflating LinearLayout in a LinearLayout with navigation drawer issue

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I am trying to inflate a LinearLayout  inside a LinearLayout. But I am not able to see the new linearlayout (with navigation drawer) on the screen. Kindly advice
By any chance is the listview inside my LinearLayout a cause of issue?

**activity_feed.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainContentScreen">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dip"
    android:maxHeight="35dip"
    android:minHeight="35dip"
    android:minWidth="10dip"
    android:maxWidth="10dip" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_submit_post.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/submitPostLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Title."
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:text="Content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/submitPostSubmitButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the java code that I have in my activity where I am trying to inflate linearlayout in a linearlayout:

```
        case 6:
            View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(
                    getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_submit_post, null);
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContentScreen)).addView(viewToLoad);
            break;
```

Please note that for first 5 cases I am loading my data in the **listview** of **activity_feed.xml** and it is working fine.

Comment: First, you should be using your `Activity`'s `Context` for the `LayoutInflater`. Second, you're adding that inflated `View` to a vertical `LinearLayout` that already has a `ListView`that fills it, so it's off-screen below the `ListView`.

Comment: before adding any other view to Linear layout please make sure that you don't have any child views to it. If it has any child view remove all the views,then add the inflated view to Linear layout.